# Bridging 2 docker-compose solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

In my line of work, I’m working with MS Visual Studio, Docker for Windows and VS’s Docker tooling.
I’m working on a multi-container solution that has dependencies on containers with long startup times (such as elasticsearch). I’ve experimented with the docker-compose 2.4 format and successfully used the depends_on with healthchecks combination in order to ensure the startup order of my projects. This however, negatively impacts my developement experience, as it takes a long amount of time to start my solution (using the VS / .dcproj / docker-compose integration) or to attach the debugger to it.

I’m looking to optimize my developement experience, while retaining the guarantee that my dependencies are up and running before my under-developement containers are being launched.

- I was wondering if it would be a good solution to have the dependencies such as elasticsearch/consul etc. started up as a separate docker-compose solution and have it run side-by-side ?
- Is it possible to bridge 2 docker-compose solutions using docker-network and preferable retain the docker network dns?
- Is there a better conceptual solution than this?
  Best regards

Comment: Does it make sense for you to deploy the data stores locally via Docker, leave them running, and develop your application locally talking to them?  That would let you easily use your local IDE tooling, not mess around with the Docker build cycle and filesystem-permission problems, but still get you the benefit of easily starting up and destroying one-off databases.

Comment: Initially it did, but I have a growing amount of inter-dependent containers. consider a web-api container that requires IdentityServer v4 as it's identity provider + ELK as it's telemetry store + PostgreSQL as its data store